# Generic solution for rounding numbers to nearest 100s, 1000s and all?

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I am working on an application where there is a need for getting the numbers rounded in the below fashion:

1. 45   50
2. 150  200
3. 201  400
4. 461  500
5. 502  1000
6. 560  1000

I can make use of the following code for rounding to 1000s and 5000s.

```
if (maxValue < 10000)
{
    modifiedMaxvalue = (int)Math.Ceiling(dMax / 1000) * 1000;
}
else
{
    modifiedMaxvalue = (int)Math.Ceiling(dMax / 5000) * 5000;
}
```

Is there a generic way we can achieve the same for ones, tens, hundreds...till millions?

Comment: Maybe you can make use of Math.Log10(...)? Log10(1000) = 3, Log10(10000) = 4, etc

Comment: Hi Nikhil, The purpose is to getting the next rounded value. The rounded value can be in 100s if the input is 10s. And it can be in 1000s if the input is in 100s.

Comment: There is no logic there, just caos... if you want a generic way you shuld have a generic rule.. Why 201 rounds to 400? why 502 rounds to 1000? while 45 rounds to 50 and 150 rounds to 200?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what your question title says, but not exactly what your example shows:

```
public static int RoundUp(int value) {
  int n = 10;
  while (n * 10 < value) n *= 10;
  return (value + n - 1) / n * n;
}
```

It returns these results:

```
 45  ->   50
150  ->  200
201  ->  300
461  ->  500
502  ->  600
560  ->  600
```

And also:

```
        4 ->        10
     2506 ->      3000
    15700 ->     20000
   258000 ->    300000
  5870000 ->   6000000
 38780000 ->  40000000
308700000 -> 400000000
```

#### Edit:

Here is a safer version, which won't go into an infinite loop for very large values:

```
public static int RoundUp(int value) {
  long n = 10, v = value;
  while (n * 10 < v) n *= 10;
  return (int)((v + n - 1) / n * n);
}
```

This can handle values up to 2000000000 (as anything over that will round up to a value that can't be represented as an `int`):

```
1705600000 -> 2000000000
```